# PHP - Logout script not working. Logged in even if variable should be false

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables, session-state

My php code keeps always logged in. The logout does not work either. There has to be some lidde error I cant spot.

I echoed the $_SESSION['logged] and it's always 1. 
But the $_POST['nam'] is indeed empty. So it does not keep the data when opening the site. 
The if-funtion for the true login, doesn't resolve true neither.

Im sorry for posting so much code, but maybe it is the mySQL part?

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

mysqli_connect($servername,$dbuser,$dbpw,$db,$port); //DB-Conn succesfull

      $query  =   "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE '$user' AND `pw` LIKE '$pw'";
      $result =   mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
      $rows   =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      if($_POST['name']==$rows['name']) {
          $_SESSION['logged']    =   true;
          echo "Not triggering, still logged in";
      }
      else { $_SESSION['logged']    =   false;}

      if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
          $_SESSION = array();
          session_destroy();
          $_SESSION['logged'] = false;}

     echo $_SESSION['logged']; //This is always 1
  }
```

The form

```
          <?php     if($_SESSION['logged'] == false) {?>

                            <form method="post">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="abc">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw" name="pw" placeholder="xyz">
                              <button type="submit" name="send">Login</button>
                            </form>        
            <?php ;}
            else {?>
                    <form method="post">
                      <button type="submit" id="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
                    </form>

            <?php }
            ?>
```

Comment: No reason means?

Comment: That's not much code, it's more like it is too little. I cannot find a real error in this code. You do know about [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)?

Comment: Show us your form, so we can see what `send` and `logout` in there actually are. If they are both submit buttons, then of course your logic doesn’t work, because no form gets submitted by pressing two submit buttons at the same time, that is not even technically possible.

Comment: No reason means that $_SESSION['logged'] is true, even if there is no code which sets it to true. I mean, I cant find that part :/

Comment: Its for a school project, SQL-Injection protection comes later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see you are wrapping the entire script in `if ($_POST["send"])` statement

But in your form the `$_POST["send"]` is only going to exist on login form not on logout form.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible is because `if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {` does not evaluate to true.

The part does not get executed. I guess you don't have `$_POST['logout']` but `$_GET['logout']` **or** inside your `<form>` the `<input name='logout'>` does not have a value.

**It is impossible, for a variable set to `true` to be `false` right in the next line.**

There is a very very tiny chance of a race condition in case you are using sessions that are not locked during the request, which is default when you use HHVM instead of PHP for example - but I doubt that in your case.

Comment: added the form, I hope this helps. And thank you for the fast answer

Comment: Look, I gave you the correct answer five minutes before you show the actual form ;-) `$_POST['logout']` **is not set** -  it has no value.

Comment: And it is $_Post

Comment: Also because of what Grover says. You don't have `$_POST['send']` in the logout `<form>`.

Comment: It was even simpler. I had the logout if-condition wrapped inside the login if-condition. I mean, technically you were right of course and thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some command in this case.I have corrected as below.Session will not save anything after the execute session_destroy.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $rows['name']="Done";
    if ($_POST['name'] == $rows['name']) {
        $_SESSION['logged']    =   true;
        echo "Not triggering, still logged in <br/>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['logged']    =   false;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['logout'])) 
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    $_SESSION['logged'] = false;
    unset($_SESSION['logged']);
    session_destroy();
}
echo(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && ($_SESSION['logged']))? 'true' : 'false';
?>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || !($_SESSION['logged'])) { ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="abc">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw" name="pw" placeholder="xyz">
        <button type="submit" name="send">Login</button>
    </form>
<?php
} else { ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <button type="submit" id="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
    </form>
<?php }
?>
```